# Strip a leading zero with JavaScript / DoJo?

Tags: javascript, string, dojo

The back end returns me days of the month, single digit days padded with a leading 0, what is the most efficient and browser-friendly way of stripping that leading zero? It's not hard code-wise, I am just not sure what the "correct" and most "efficient" way is. Here's how I do it now...kind of a simplistic way:

```
                    if (newValue[0] === "0")
                    newValue = newValue[1];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take a string from second char, use

```
if (newValue[0] === "0") newValue = newValue.slice(1);
```

You could also remove all leading 0 using a regexp :

```
newValue = newValue.replace(/^0+/, '')
```

Note that it's possible that what you need is in fact a conversion, that is to get the number from the string. This can be done with

```
newValue = +newValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` ignores them, so you could just do `""+parseInt(newValue, 10)`.